# Compress data and ignore empty cell

Tags: r

I have the following database and I want to compress it ignoring `NA` and group by column `x` and have one record per row.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c("efg", "hij", "abc", "abc"), y=c("P","K",NA,"R"), z=c("J",NA,"L",NA))
```

I am using the following and seems it does not work well

```
library(plyr)
d_2 = ddply(d,.(x,na.omit(y),na,omit(z)),frequency)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `ddply(na.omit(d),.(x,y,z),frequency)` `na.omit` uses typically a  data frame as input, and removes all rows containing at least one `NA`

Comment: all rows with NA will be removed if using your suggestion. I dont need to remove the entire row

Comment: Can you please show your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely not the most elegant code but it does work for your limited test case above.

```
#Define the dataframe with strings and not factors
d <- data.frame(x=c("efg", "hij", "abc", "abc"), 
                y=c("P","K",NA,"R"), 
                z=c("J",NA,"L",NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d[is.na(d)]<-"" #removes the NAs
#aggregate the rows
out<-aggregate(d[2:3], by=list(d$x), FUN=toString)
names(out)[1]<-"x"  #Renames the first column
#Removes any commas added from the aggregated/toString command 
#and set the results back to a data frame
d<-data.frame(apply(out, MARGIN=c(1,2), FUN=gsub, pattern=", ", replacement=""))
```

The aggregate line can be adjusted to suit multiple columns.
I would have like to have used the dplyr library's groupby and summarize functions but I was unable to apply the operation across multiple columns.